# How fix when the keyboard appears?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

i have a table with a textField in a cell y under this table i have a textField

```
-------------------------------------------
- --------------------------------------- -
- -        text field in table          - -
- ------------------------------------- - -
-------------------------------------------


- --------------------------------------- -
- -     other        textField          - -
- ------------------------------------- - -
```

then i did a library for the entrance the keyboard

```
public static void KeyBoardUpNotification(NSNotification notification)
        {
            scrollamount = 0.0f;

            RectangleF rectangle = (RectangleF)UIKeyboard.BoundsFromNotification(notification);
            if (currentView == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (activeview==null) {
                foreach (UIView view in currentView.Subviews)
                {
                    if (view.IsFirstResponder)
                    {
                        activeview = view;
                        activeview.BecomeFirstResponder();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (activeview == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            bottom = ((float)(activeview.Frame.Y + activeview.Frame.Height + offset));
            scrollamount = ((float)(rectangle.Height - (currentView.Frame.Size.Height - bottom)));

            if (scrollamount != 0)
            {
                moveViewUp = true;
                ScrollTheView(moveViewUp);
            }
            else
            {
                moveViewUp = false;
            }
        }

        public static void KeyBoardDownNotification(NSNotification notification)
        {
            if (moveViewUp) ScrollTheView(false);
        }

        private static void ScrollTheView(bool move)
        {
            UIView.BeginAnimations(string.Empty, IntPtr.Zero);
            UIView.SetAnimationDuration(0.3);
            RectangleF frame = (RectangleF)currentView.Frame;

            if (move)
            {
                frame.Y = y;
                frame.Y -= scrollamount;    
            }
            else
            {
                frame.Y = y;
                scrollamount = 0;
                moveViewUp = false;
            }
            currentView.Frame = frame;
            UIView.CommitAnimations();
            scrollamount = 0;
            frame.Y = 0;
        }
```

but when the focus is in textfield from cell this code donot work, the camera focuses on the textField below.

but this code only work in textfield below, the camera focuses on the textField below and that is good.

Comment: Can you please give me a sample project? I tried your code but failed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: BTW, I think you should move up the `Tableview` instead of the `Textfield` when the `TextField` in the cell `focused`.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT that is my problem, how i move up?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT this foreach (UIView view in currentView.Subviews) is dont find in tthe tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a tag to `belowTextfield` and compare it with `activeview`, then decide to move up the `belowTextField` or `tableView`

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        UITextField belowTextField = new UITextField();

        belowTextField.Tag = 1;
    }


  public void test() {

        if (activeview == null)
        {
            foreach (UIView view in currentView.Subviews)
            {
                if (view.IsFirstResponder)
                {
                    activeview = view;
                    activeview.BecomeFirstResponder();
                }
            }
        }

        UITextField tempView = activeview as UITextField;

        if (tempView.Tag == 1)
        {
            //move up bellowTextField
        }
        else { 
            //move up tableView
        }
    }
```